# Get all the object using a field value- SOQL

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query

I have a custom object called abc__c , which has a field(text)-> field__c. I would like to get all the records where field__c value is "Hello". How can write a query for this in query editor.

I tried :

```
Select Id From abc__c where field__c='hello';
```

But this says unknown error parsing query. What is the right way to query the records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Query Editor of Developer Console there is no need to end the query with semi colon.

If you remove the ; it will work without any issues.